# mysql select most popular tags in most popular categories

Tags: mysql, join

I have database with tables like this:

```
articles
-----------
id,
category_id,
name

threads
-----------
id,
category_id,
name

tags
------------
id,
name

tags_articles
------------
id,
article_id,
tag_id

tags_threads
------------
id,
thread_id,
tag_id
```

What i need is query which returns 5 most popular tags in 5 most popular categories.

So results could look like this:
category_id, category_name, tag_id, tag_name
1,           cars           2     , red
1,           cars           4     , events
1,           cars           8     , wheels
1,           cars           9     , some tag name
1,           cars           10    , another tag name
4,           cars           44     , tag44name
4,           cars           4     , events
4,           cars           88    , tag88name
4,           cars           9     , some tag name
4,           cars           28    , tag28name
and 3 more groups here

I know i must use "union" for joining sets from articles and threads tables and then emulate partition over function but it's to complicated for me.
Regards

Comment: What formula determines top within a top? So if we get the 5 most popular tags first and then the top 5 categories is that sufficient?  or should we get the most popular categories first and then the top 5 tags in those categories.  or is there some weighted values we should be using for each?  Different approaches here can yield different results.

Comment: Are we looking for a total of 5 results, or are we looking for a total of 25 results?

Comment: Query must return 5 groups with 5 tags so total rows will be 25. If it comes to what should be first i must say that i am not sure. I think 5 most popular categories are categories having greatest amount of tags .

Comment: What is the meaning of popular category? Is this judged by maximum count of tags OR the maximum counts of article+thread? This would be helpful in writing a query.

Comment: I think 5 most popular categories are categories having greatest amount of tags .